# What Django version does GAE support?

Tags: django, google-app-engine

This link https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27 suggest "1.5" & "Latest" but doesn't exactly specify 'Latest'. Also, who knows when was this document updated. If any of you guys have been deploying your apps on GAE, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK release notes contain this information.

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes

> Django 1.5.4 has been upgraded to 1.5.8.

So currently looks like 1.5.8 is the latest. Where there might be a central list of what version you can use if you want I don't know.